# How to prevent forms moving of screen

Tags: forms, delphi, helper, message

I use the following helper for preventing forms moving of screen and it is most of the time working OK. But if I open a wsNormal form in a MDI app then the form might show up of the area where it is supposed to be. I can then just move it a bit and then the unit here takes over and moves it in place.
My question is now: how can I either prevent this from happening or send a message to the form saying it is moving so the unit her can do its job.

```
unit U_FormsMove;

interface

uses
  Messages, Windows, Forms;

{$M+}

type
  TForm = class(Forms.TForm)
  private
  protected
    procedure WMMoving(var message : TWMMoving); message WM_MOVING;
  published
  public
  end;

implementation

function GetMovementArea: TRect;
var
  MovementRect: TRect;
begin
  if Application.MainForm.FormStyle = fsMDIForm then
    Windows.GetWindowRect(Application.MainForm.ClientHandle, MovementRect)
  else
    SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETWORKAREA, 0, @MovementRect, 0);
  if MovementRect.Top < 150 then
    MovementRect.Top := 150;
  MovementRect.Top := MovementRect.Top + 5;
  MovementRect.Left := MovementRect.Left + 5;
  MovementRect.Right := MovementRect.Right - 5;
  MovementRect.Bottom := MovementRect.Bottom - 5;
  Result := MovementRect;
end;

{ TFormHelper }
procedure TForm.WMMoving(var Message: TWMMoving);
var
  rec: ^TRect;
  wrk: TRect;
begin
  wrk := GetMovementArea;
  rec := Pointer(Message.DragRect);
  if rec^.Left < wrk.Left then
    begin
      rec^.Right := rec^.Right - (rec^.Left - wrk.Left);
      rec^.Left := wrk.Left;
    end
  else if rec^.Right > wrk.Right then
    begin
      rec^.Left := rec^.Left - (rec^.Right - wrk.Right);
      rec^.Right := wrk.Right;
    end;
  if rec^.Top < wrk.Top then
    begin
      rec^.Bottom := rec^.Bottom - (rec^.Top - wrk.Top);
      rec^.Top := wrk.Top;
    end
  else if rec^.Bottom > wrk.Bottom then
    begin
      rec^.Top := rec^.Top - (rec^.Bottom - wrk.Bottom);
      rec^.Bottom := wrk.Bottom;
    end;
end;


end.
```

Comment: Why not post a `WM_MOVING` message in the `OnShow` event?

Comment: @Sertac Akyuz 
I know that - this will be in the next version of this

Comment: Note that your GetMovementArea does not support additional monitors (answered above). You can get the position of an MDI child in its OnCreate event handler, in the same handler you can set a new position.

Comment: @LU RD
You are absolutly right - why not. (It does the trick as far as I can see)